# Rotating the angle of my shape, depdning on the mouses position.

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glut

I am trying to `rotate` my shape to the `mouses X and Y position`. Like in 2D top down games, a `tank's turret` will rotate to the `mouses X` and `Y position`.

Using

```
glutPassiveMotionFunc(MousePassiveMotion);
```

I am able to record the X and Y position;

```
void MousePassiveMotion(int x, int y){
    //do something here
    myAtan2 = atan2(y - Pentagon.y, x - Pentagon.x)* 180 / PI;
    Pentagon.angle = myAtan2;
    cout << Pentagon.angle << endl;
}
```

The debug gives me a value between `0` and `90` at max I believe.

How ever, my Pentagon is not rotating.

```
void DrawShape(){

    glTranslatef(x, y, z);//the x and y position of the shape 

    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex3f(v[9].x, v[9].y, v[9].z);
```

The top code is a `struct`, called `Shape{};` that Pentagon is type of. 
The `DrawShape()` method gets called in the `display function`, so it should be rotating. but is not.

Does any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling `glutPostRedisplay()` in your mouse callback(s) xor in an idle/timer callback.  Otherwise your display callback will only get called (and your pentagon redrawn with the new angle) when the OS feels like it.